# .htaccess password protect a file in a certain directory

Tags: linux, .htaccess, directory, files, password-protected

I have files with the same name in different directories on the serves (example: stats.php), and I want to password protect some of them (.htaccess file in the root directory). I tried "FilesMatch" with a path to the file and it didn't work, and I tried adding "Directory" path as follows, same problem.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/folder/httpdocs/directory/>
<FilesMatch "stats.php">
AuthName "Private file"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/whatever/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `.htaccess` file in the root directory doesn't work for this purpose. You must place a new [`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) file to every directory where you need divergent settings from its parent(s):

> `.htaccess` files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way
>   to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file,
>   containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a
>   particular document directory, and **the directives apply to that
>   directory, and all subdirectories thereof**.

The [`<Directory>` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) is only allowed in *server config* and *virtual host* contexts. The `.htaccess` file is its equivalent placed directly to the directory. You have two options:

- Create `/var/www/vhosts/folder/httpdocs/directory/.htaccess` with the `<FilesMatch "stats.php">`. This is the only method if you don't have access to the server configuration.
- Place the `<Directory /var/www/vhosts/folder/httpdocs/directory/>` in *server config* or in *virtual host*. This is better in performance as it's loaded once when Apache starts, rather than on every request.

Comment: You say: Place the <Directory /var/www/vhosts/folder/httpdocs/directory/> in server config.  Just this line? for each directory that has .htaccess?

Comment: No, the whole block. Only IF you use it instead of the `.htaccess` approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache 2.4 you can use an [If Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) that matches against the request to determine if authorization should be required or not as follows:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /stats.php$/">
    AuthName "Private file"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /var/www/whatever/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
</If>
```